# Porting an example from QuantEcon.jl to POMDPs.jl

Tags: julia, dynamic-programming

I asked this in the [Julia discourse website](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/porting-an-example-from-quantecon-jl-to-pomdps-jl/16377) but got no response. I'm asking over here to see if I have better luck.

Just for fun (and to learn about POMDP) I am porting an example of dynamic programming from QuantEcon.jl to POMDPs.jl. The example is available [here](https://lectures.quantecon.org/jl/discrete_dp.html#example-a-growth-model).

My code for the implementation is:

```
using POMDPs
using POMDPModels
using POMDPModelTools
using DiscreteValueIteration

struct SimpleOG{TI <: Integer, T <: Real, TR <: AbstractArray{T}, TQ <: AbstractArray{T}} <: MDP{T, T}
    B :: TI
    M :: TI
    α :: T
    β :: T
    R :: TR
    Q :: TQ
end

function SimpleOG(; B::Integer = 10, M::Integer = 5, α::T = 0.5, β::T = 0.90) where {T <: Real}

    u(c) = c^α # utility function
    n = B + M + 1
    m = M + 1

    R = Matrix{T}(undef, n, m)
    Q = zeros(Float64, n, m, n)

    for a in 0:M
        Q[:, a + 1, (a:(a + B)) .+ 1] .= 1 / (B + 1)
        for s in 0:(B + M)
            R[s + 1, a + 1] = a <= s ? u(s - a) : -Inf
        end
    end

    return SimpleOG(B, M, α, β, R, Q)
end

POMDPs.states(simpleog::SimpleOG) = collect(0:(simpleog.M + simpleog.B))
POMDPs.n_states(simpleog::SimpleOG) = simpleog.B + simpleog.M + 1
POMDPs.stateindex(simpleog::SimpleOG, s) = Int(s) + 1

POMDPs.actions(simpleog::SimpleOG) = collect(0:simpleog.M)
POMDPs.n_actions(simpleog::SimpleOG) = simpleog.M + 1
POMDPs.actionindex(simpleog::SimpleOG, a) = Int(a) + 1

POMDPs.transition(simpleog::SimpleOG, s, a) = simpleog.Q[Int(a) + 1, Int(s) + 1, :]

POMDPs.reward(simpleog::SimpleOG, s, a) = simpleog.R[Int(s), Int(a)]
POMDPs.reward(simpleog::SimpleOG, s, a, sp) = reward(simpleog, s, a)

POMDPs.discount(simpleog::SimpleOG) = simpleog.β

g = SimpleOG()
```

When I try to solve the model I get:

```
julia> POMDPs.solve(g)
MethodError: no method matching solve(::SimpleOG{Int64,Float64,Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,3}})
Closest candidates are:
  solve(!Matched::POMDPPolicies.FunctionSolver, !Matched::Union{MDP, POMDP}) at /Users/amrods/.julia/packages/POMDPPolicies/oW6ud/src/function.jl:23
  solve(!Matched::POMDPPolicies.RandomSolver, !Matched::Union{MDP, POMDP}) at /Users/amrods/.julia/packages/POMDPPolicies/oW6ud/src/random.jl:36
  solve(!Matched::POMDPPolicies.VectorSolver{A}, !Matched::MDP{S,A}) where {S, A} at /Users/amrods/.julia/packages/POMDPPolicies/oW6ud/src/vector.jl:23
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[14]:1
```

Can you help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: ... And the question is?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to copy the last part of the question now edited in.

Comment: Have you checked POMDPs&#39; documentation? It seems that `solve` requires a solver and a problem (two parameters) . You give only one parameter. http://juliapomdp.github.io/POMDPs.jl/latest/api.html#POMDPs.solve

Also, there are some helpful commands that will tell you what you miss if problem still persists. Please check the documentation and the FAQ of POMDPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What hckr said: POMDP.jl defines a standard interface, kinda like JuMP.jl.

After defining your model, you need a solver to, well, solve it.

[QMDP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/QMDP.jl) is one, [SARSOP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/SARSOP.jl) is another, or plain old [discrete value iteration](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/DiscreteValueIteration.jl) could work too.
You can get onboard the deep learning hype and try [Deep Q Learning](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/DeepQLearning.jl) too.

There are lots of different solver algorithms, and you can write your own too (see the POMDP.jl [docs](https://juliapomdp.github.io/POMDPs.jl/latest/def_solver.html) and examples).

[Dr Kochenderfer's book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/decision-making-under-uncertainty) runs through a lot of them (full disclosure, he was my teacher), as do many, many [papers](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~jpineau/files/jpineau-jaamas12-finalcopy.pdf)

Edit:
As for the `pdf` bit (this was too long for a comment):
Unfortunately theres a lot going on with these packages.
So there are a couple related examples to that notebook [here (an older one)](https://github.com/sisl/aa228-notebook/blob/master/08-MarkovDecisionProcesses.ipynb) and a slightly more relevant one [here](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/POMDPModels.jl/blob/master/src/gridworld.jl). Unfortunately neither mention `pdf`, but other examples (TMazes and Tabular) do, as does this other [older example](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/POMDPExamples.jl/blob/b9e3f39fbef6434b3f6487db1e17d618630198fc/legacy/Tiger.ipynb).

**Burying the lead, [this](https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/POMDPExamples.jl/blob/7e4af2fb21e18178184c1fe706f81112156b8e5e/notebooks/Defining-a-POMDP-with-the-Explicit-Interface.ipynb) looks like your best bet for a walk through and [this](https://juliapomdp.github.io/POMDPs.jl/latest/explicit.html) for documentation**
`transition(::MDP, ::State, ::Action)` returns some sort of distribution object to be fed into `pdf`.
It could be `<:Distributions.Distribution` or not. All it has to be is a representation of `T(s' | s, a) = pdf(transition(mdp, s, a), s')`.
Since MDPs are probabilistic in nature, an explicit interface requires a quantification of the transition probabilities between states given actions.

Hope that helps, and sorry its such a hectic ... everything. I know the lab, they'd love any feedback on your issues thusfar with the documentation and any help you can spare with pull requests :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Let's say that I'm using `DiscreteValueIteration`. `@requirements_info ValueIterationSolver() SimpleOG()` says that I need to implement `pdf` but I couldn't find any example in which `pdf` is defined (also notice that the link to the tutorial in the documentation is broken). Could you provide an example about how to do that, to define `pdf`?